# C Compiler differences for iOS and Android development

Tags: android, ios, c, compiler-construction, casting

We just stumbled on a bug in the Android version of our app that is caused by a compiler difference on iOS and Android.  Curious if someone can explain the difference and how to make the Android native C compiler work like iOS.  Here is a simplified version of the problem.

```
double zone = -7 / 24.0;
char command[80] = { '\0' };
```

// other stuff

```
command[7] = zone * 24.0;
```

Ignore the possible roundoff errors in the above.  This is a simplified example.

On iOS, command[7] gets the value -7 put into.  This is what I would expect since there should be an automatic cast from double to char (or int) when doing the assignment.

On Android, using the native C compiler, we get 0 put into command[7].  If we explicitly cast it like

```
command[7] = (int)(zone * 24.0);
```

Then it gets the same result as iOS.

Does anyone know why the two compilers might be generating different code?  If there a compiler flag on Android to make the compiler behave as in iOS?  The app has been extensively tested on iOS and we are a bit leery about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android C implementation, `char` is unsigned, and the conversion from -7 in `double` to `char` is producing zero. (The behavior of this conversion when the value cannot be represented in the destination type is not defined by the C standard.)

In iOS, `char` is signed, and the conversion of -7 in `double` to `char` produces -7.

The compiler may have an `-fsigned-char` switch that will make `char` signed, or you could change `char command[80]…` to `signed char command[80]…`.

This explains why `command[7] = (int)(zone * 24.0);` gets the desired results:

- When you cast the result to `int` before assigning it to `command[7]`, the -7 in `double` is converted to -7 in `int`. Then this `int` is converted to an unsigned `char`. That conversion is defined by the C standard, and the result is CHAR_MAX+1-7 (249 in typical C implementations with unsigned `char`). That is not the same result on iOS (-7) and Android (249), but they are represented with the same bits. Presumably, they act the same in whatever further use you put them to.

Comment: Adding the -fsigned-char flag to Android.mk did indeed fix the problem.  Thanks much for the analysis.